# Associate custom post types with normal posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type, called App. This has details like the name, description, thumbnail image, and some custom fields.

Then I have posts about this app, that I'd like to associate with it. In the end, I'd like to be able to view the custom post type and all the posts that are associated with it.

But I don't see any way to associate a post with anything besides a category or tag. But categories and tags don't allow for custom fields, images, etc.

Is the only way to create a category with the same name as the custom post type, and then do something like have a custom field in that custom post type that has the ID of that category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't really have to create a category to associate your different post types. You can use this great [Post 2 Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin by scribu. It does exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Excellent - I'm surprised this isn't built into Wordpress. Thanks!